# Is it possible to invoke webview onclicking imageview in activityview?

Tags: android

I'm doing a project with Android, and I'm wondering if it is possible to invoke a web view from an activity view? If so, how can that be done?

As an example, I have an image in an activity view, and on  click, I'd like it to open a web view with a specific URL.

Comment: Yes I can assure you this is possible.

Comment: I reversed my decision to close this and edited it instead. Please make note of my edits for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(intent);  
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a tone dude... dude one more question is it possible to get back from browser screen to app scree( i mean from browser to activity view screen)???

Comment: First of all, there are 2 ways to implement webview: 1. Webview within app 2. Webview open outside (as in answer), so if you want to implement BACK and FORWARD navigation then you should implement WebViewClient, for example: http://goo.gl/ofuL9

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  create an activity that contains the webview. In it's oncreate, you tell it to load the url.

In the activity where you have your ImageView, you set an onClickListener on the ImageView. In that onClickListener, you start the Activity(using startActivity) to open the activity containing the webview.